# How to save find/replace settings in Eclipse?

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

Eclipse has a pretty awesome find/replace system with regex support.  I find that I use a lot of the same regex find/replaces on a regular basis.  The Eclipse find/replace dialog does store the last several finds commands in a combobox, but anything older than 8 or so finds gets pushed out.  Also, it doesn't store the find and replace commands together as one setting, it's just storing the most recently used for both separately.

Is there any way in Eclipse (or possibly a plugin for Eclipse) that stores find/replace commands together along with other settings (i.e. Case Sensitive, etc.)

Comment: That's a good question, but in what way is it related to python?

Comment: This might be a better question for programmers.stackexchange or superuser

Answer (score 3):

Been using Eclipse since version 3.0 whenever that was released. I never seen the functionality you describe. Perhaps you should post it as a request at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/